# Updating submodule repo in Jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, git-submodules

What I need to do is as follows:

There's a git repository which is used as a submodule in few other repositories. Each main repository holds a reference to a different branch in the submodule repository. (Actually most of them refer to the same branch, and few others to different branches).
What I want to do is, to have a Jenkins job that clones a parent-repo, updates the submodule (So I'll have the relevant revision of the submodule corresponding to the parent repo), do some work there, update a `version.txt` file **in the submodule** and push it back to git.

My problem is, that the submodule  revision is being checked out as DETACHED HEAD.
While this problem maybe overcome in the regular `checkout` using the `Checkout to local branch` option, it doesn't seem to hold for submodules.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

*All* submodules use detached-HEAD mode.  That's just the way submodules work.

Remember that a Git submodule *is* a Git repository.  So it's just an ordinary repository at the time it gets cloned: a collection of commits, joined together by their metadata to form history, with branch and tag names selecting particularly interesting commits, from which we can find all other commits.

What makes the submodule a *submodule*, rather than just "a repository", is that *after* it is cloned—usually by the superproject, which is the controlling Git repository "above" the submodule—the *superproject* Git selects one particular commit *in* the submodule repository.

If we call the superproject **R** and the submodule **S** (so that we can tell them apart), what we've done is this:

```
mkdir -p path/to/project && cd path/to/project
git clone $superproject R
git clone --no-checkout $submodule R/S
chosen_commit=$(cd R; git command-to-tell-me-which-hash-ID S)
(cd R/S && git checkout --detach $chosen_commit)
```

We don't literally run a Git command to show us the right hash ID—though there is one; it's simply `git rev-parse`, e.g., `(cd R; git rev-parse HEAD:S)` does the trick—but that's the *effect* of the commands that we *do* run:

```
mkdir R && cd R && git clone $superproject && git submodule update --init
```

The `git submodule update --init` command will, for each submodule:

- clone the submodule, with `--no-checkout`, getting the URL from `.gitmodules`;
- figure out which commit to check out by doing the appropriate `git rev-parse`; and
- check out that particular commit, as a detached HEAD, *in* the corresponding submodule's working tree.

In this manner, *each commit in **R*** stores the right hash ID to check out in **S**.  The superproject **R** cannot store a *branch name* because branch names *move*, and we want one fixed commit.  It could, in theory, store a tag name, because in theory tag names don't move; but that's not how it got implemented.  So we're stuck with what *did* get implemented—and in any case, doing `git checkout` on a tag name results in a detached HEAD too.

Note that in Git, a hash ID *is* the name of the commit.  A branch or tag name is just a human-readable alias—well, an alias that we can *hope* makes sense to a human.  It's the hash ID that really matters, though.  And, in a submodule, the source of the *correct* hash ID is the superproject's commit—which only stores the raw hash ID.  That is all we have, so that is all you can get.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the with the following Powershell script:

```
// Get-SubmoduleBranch

param(
    [parameter(mandatory)]
    [string]$SubmoduleName,
    [parameter(mandatory)]
    [string]$GitmodulesFile
)

$IsCorrectSubmodule = $False
$Found = $False
Switch -Regex -File $GitmodulesFile {
    "Submodule .*$($SubmoduleName)" { $IsCorrectSubmodule = $True }
    "branch" {
        if($IsCorrectSubmodule) {
            $Found = $True
            $Pair = $_ -split "="
            $Pair[1].Trim() # Output the branch name
            break
             }
    }

}

if($Found -eq $False) {
  Write-Error “Didn’t find submodule branch”
}
```

And in the Jenkinsfile

```
powershell script: """
 \$Branch = Get-SubmoduleBranch -SubmoduleName <someSubmodule> -GitmodulesFile .gitmodules

git checkout \$Branch
git add
git commit
git push 

"""
```